Should the wife obey her husband in the matters of housework?
I have searched about the question and some similar topics in islamweb, islamqa and other questions on this page. According the fatwas and answers I have till now comprehended that-

A wife is not obliged to do housework as it is not in the marriage contract. But it is encouraged to do so, if the husband is not able to hire a maid or cook.

The wife is obliged to obey the husband in all matter that are not haram and not beyond her capacity.


So, my question is that if a man is able to arrange for a maid but not a cook (financial reasons) can he ask his wife to do the cooking? As even though she is not obliged by default to do household works, she has to obey him in what is within her capacity and not haram.
Moreover certain hadith also depicts that women used to do that when the husband was not able to afford a servant.
And this hadith states that woman is responsible for the house of her husband -

Ibn 'Umar reported that the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, "All of you are shepherds and each of you is responsible for his flock. A man is the shepherd of the people of his house and he is responsible. A woman is the shepherd of the house of her husband and she is responsible. Each of you is a shepherd and each is responsible for his flock."
Classed as Sahih (Al Albani).
Collected from sunnah.com


See Why is cooking and cleaning not the duty of the wife?

@UmH Yes, I have already read that but most fatwas and scholars like Assim al Hakeem agrees that she is obliged to obey him in matters which are not haram and within her capacity. That is why I am asking that if he asks / better requests her to do it, then?

And also this link-
https://www.reddit.com/r/SistersInSunnah/comments/x93yen/is_a_wife_religiously_obligated_to_take_care_of/?rdt=53432

"Assim al Hakeem agrees that she is obliged to obey him in matters which are not haram" this isn't an explicite statement about housework and this is also something agreed upon even if the majority of scholars hold the opinion that it isn't "fard": a religious obligation on her. The hadith you've shared mainly focuses on two tasks of the wife: child education and organizing and house keeping (budget) of the household as per hadith commentaries.

@Media1Saif you seem to misunderstand the point. I definitely know that it isn't a compulsory obligation. What I am saying is what if the husband asks her to do a part of housework and if that is the norm of the society, not something out of box. Shall she do that? And for the hadith part it states that man is the shepherd of the people of the house. And scholars agree that the man should educate his wife and children in the path of Islam.

There is a difference of opinion as to whether housework is a wife's duty.
The dominant opinion among the Shafi’is and the Hanbalis is that housework is not an obligation on the wife, however, it is better for her to do it, especially if it is customary for wives to engage in housework.
On the other hand, Hanafis and Malikis typically consider housework as a woman’s duty, drawing from how the Prophet ﷺ divided tasks between Ali and Fatimah, radhi allahu 'anhuma: Ali handled external affairs while Fatimah took care of the home.
However, interestingly, Hanafi scholars emphasize that housework is a moral/religious duty rather than a legal one, meaning that while the wife is ethically responsible to do the housework, if she refuses to do so, she will only be advised but the court cannot compel her.
Maliki scholars typically differentiate between women from affluent families and other women; pointing out that if a woman was accustomed to having servants before marriage, and her husband can afford it, he should hire help rather than expect her to do the housework.
The specific type of housework that a woman is required to do depends on the local custom (urf). For example, a villager might have to do chores that a city-dweller does not need to do, and vice versa.
If a woman is unable or unwilling to do the type of housework that the local custom requires her to do, she has to indicate that before marriage; so that the suitor can either find another arrangement, or decide to marry another woman who is happy to do the type of housework required.
As for obedience, while there is a consensus that a wife should obey her husband, there is disagreement on the extent of the obedience that is required.
Some scholars, notably Ibn Najim al-Hanafi, have argued that the wife is only required to obey her husband in sexual intimacy and matters related to it (e.g. not leaving the house or allowing a visitor inside without his permission). As for other permissible commands, it is commendable to obey the husband but not obligatory.

المرأة لا يجب عليها طاعة الزوج في كل ما يأمر به، إنما ذلك فيما يرجع
إلى النكاح وتوابعه
A woman is not obliged to obey her husband in everything he commands, but only in sexual intimacy, and matters
relating to it.

However, most scholars are of the view that a wife should obey her husband in everything, including housework, unless he asks her to do something haram or harmful.
يجب أن تطيعه في كل ما أمرها به من المعروف

She must obey him in everything he commands that is permissible.
— Imam Ahmad

وحقه عليها أن تطيعه في كل مباح يأمرها به

His right over her is that she must obey him in every permissible
command
Imam Muhammad Haskafi

على الزوجة طاعة الزوج في كل ما طلب منها مما لا معصية فيه

The wife must obey her husband in everything that he asks her to do,
which does not involve sinning. — Al-Qasimi

This view is based on the unconditioned wording of the primary texts enjoining women to obey their husbands; and the legal maxim that rulings must be understood in their most general sense, unless restricted by evidence.
In summary:

While there is a difference of opinion as to whether housework is a wife's duty, it is universally accepted that it is commendable for women to do housework, following the example of the Prophetﷺ's wives, his daughters, and female companions. This is even more important if the social custom requires women to do housework.

Scholars generally agree that a wife must obey her husband, but they differ on the limits of this obedience. Some require her to obey him in everything that does not involve disobedience to Allah, while others restrict this obligation to intimacy and similar matters. According to the first opinion, she must obey him if he commands her to cook or clean, while according to the second opinion, she is not obliged to obey him in these matters.

Ultimately, marriage thrives when both the husband and the wife focus on their responsibilities rather than their rights, focus on what they can give and how they can contribute rather than thinking solely about receiving. So while it is praiseworthy for women to do housework, it is also praiseworthy for men to help in house chores, and to be appreciative of their wives' efforts, and understanding of their needs.


And Allah knows best.

Well-referenced and detailed answer!

I confess I had written some more in comments as due to certain technical glitch the later half of your answer was not visible. Thanks for the well detailed answer
